# SPARQL query: show result for individuals without some attributes, and sum two of the attributes

Tags: sparql, protege

I have to make this SPARQL query on protege:

```
PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
PREFIX owl: <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#>
PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
PREFIX xsd: <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#>
PREFIX sw:<http://www.semanticweb.org/lorep/ontologies/2022/0/untitled-ontology-16#>
SELECT  ?Name ?Surname ?test ?written ?oral ?Course
WHERE { 
      ?Candidates sw:take_parts ?Course;
      sw:Name ?Name;
      sw:Surname ?Surname;
      sw:test ?test;
      sw:written ?written;
      sw:oral ?oral;

}
```

Now I have some candidates that took only the test without taking written and oral so when I execute the query they does not show. How can I make everyone visible?
And then how could i sum the values from written and oral? I tried with `BIND(?written+?oral AS ?total)` but it doesn't seem to work

Comment: wrapping in an `OPTIONAL` pattern is the way to go for optional triple patterns

Comment: Where should I use it? I tried to apply it before but I didn't really understand where should i put it

Comment: did you check the [specs](https://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-query/#optionals)? there is an example, you have to put a full triple pattern into the `OPTIONAL`. And you should to it for each optional property then separately of course

Comment: Yes I checked them, but by doing `OPTIONAL{sw:oral ?oral}` I just obtain an error. I don't understand where the error is

Comment: Ok I made it by using `OPTIONAL{?Candidates sw:oral ?oral}`, thanks for the help!